# How to bind value in object of object using automapper in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

This is my Dto
{
"Value1": "string",
"value2": "string",
"Value3": "string",
"value34: "string",
}

I want to return in this form using automapper
{
"Value1": "string",
"value2": "string",
"props": {
"Value3": "string",
"value34: "string",
}
}

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

For mapping nested objects in the destination type, [ForPath](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html?highlight=ForPath#forpath) does the job:

```
CreateMap<YourDto, YourDestinationType>()
    .ForPath(dst => dst.props.Value3, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value3))
    .ForPath(dst => dst.props.Value34, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value34));
```